# How can I plot a quantity knowing its ratio with another variable must be constant?

Tags: graphing-functions, ratio

I'm trying to plot an equation with a varying $T$, the equation to plot being:

$$y = \frac{1}{e^{E/T}+1} $$

The problem is that $E/T$ is a constant ratio.

**Not knowing what any of quantities are, how can I plot $y \hspace{1mm}vs \hspace{1mm} T$?**

My first thought was to set $E$ as a constant, and to just take $y$ and $T$ into consideration, but $E$ isn't a constant, so I can't do this. Can I?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, $E$ is varying with $T$ in a way such that the ratio $E/T$ stays constant. If that's the case, the graph of $y$ against $T$ is going to be very boring. $y$ will stay constant when you vary $T$, hence you'll just get a straight horizontal line.